# How to execute python2 POST request on localhost

Tags: python, python-2.7, localhost

I'm newbie in the Python, Im not able to execute post request

```
def do_POST(self):
        try:
            self.send_response(301)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
            self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080')
            self.end_headers()
            ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(
                self.headers.getheader('content-type'))
            if ctype == 'multipart/form-data':
                fields = cgi.parse_multipart(self.rfile, pdict)
                messagecontent = fields.get('message')
            output = ""
            output += "<html><body>"
            output += "  Values: "
            output += " %s " % messagecontent[0]
            output += '''<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='/hello'>What would you like me to say?<input name="message" type="text" ><input type="submit" value="Submit"> </form>'''
            output += "</body></html>"
            self.wfile.write(output)
            print output
        except:
            pass
```

I'm getting an error with 501 as a error code

> Error code 501.
>
> Message: Unsupported method ('POST').
>
> Error code explanation: 501 = Server does not support this operation.

Comment: It's not clear to me. Do you want to send a POST request to a remote server or respond to an already-receive POST request. In other word: are you client or server of the POST request?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE I'm server

Comment: which framework Django? Flask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classic use case using Django is to use the `require_http_methods` decorator:

```
    @require_http_methods(["GET", "POST"])
    def my_view(request):
        # I can assume now that only GET or POST requests make it this far
        # ...
```

=> See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/decorators/

The same use case with Flask:

```
@app.route('/hello/', methods=['POST'])
def hello():
    name = request.form['yourname']
    email = request.form['youremail']
```

=> See http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#http-methods